# What data construct to allow multi-key access, even to other keys?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Before constructing some new object to perform this task, perhaps someone can point me to an existing solution or tell me what search terms I should use to research further.

My problem is that I have a small collection of related data that comes up again and again in my problem domain.

For example, suppose my company has a single field office in each state's capital:

```
'Name': 'Alabama',  'Short': 'AL', 'Capital': 'Montgomery', 'Zip': 36043
'Name': 'Colorado', 'Short': 'CO', 'Capital': 'Denver', 'Zip': 80014
...
'Name': 'Florida', 'Short': 'FL', 'Capital': 'Tallahassee', 'Zip': 32301
```

Note: There are no duplicate values.

Each business unit wants to access the zip code differently.

Accounting wants to use the state's two letter abbreviation to access the zip code (Key-to-Data).

Finance wants to use the full state name to access the zip code (Key-to-Data).

Legal (always the difficult one) would also like to get the state name given the capital (Key-to-Key).

The number of offices is small -- usually less that 4, so I would like to avoid a "heavy" approach such as a database.

Ideally, I would like to simply define this data at the top of the script as a single define.

I could of course define multiple dicts, with each key pointing to the zip code and yet another few dicts doing Key-to-Key mappings, but that seems repetive and error-prone.

What's an elegant way to implement and access this type of many-to-one but unique data?

Comment: I'd be wary of some of the assumptions here - for example, that you never need to deal with two offices in the same state, or two cities with the same name, or multi-state ZIP codes.

Comment: The data above is for example only.  I used it because it is more approachable than the short strings and hex codes of the actual (embedded) data.  Each data point is always unique and there are never more than 6 rows, usually only 3-4 rows.

Comment: It sounds like you should be using a real database, at least SQLite. It's okay for a rarely-changing SQL table to have many indexes.

Comment: 2-way memory-efficient injective mappings aren't native to Python (or any programming language I'm aware of), you would need to code this yourself in a lower-level language with a perfect hash. In my opinion, there should be an implementation for such a use case, at least when you have a small number of items. The counter-argument, of course, is "use a database".

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution I wound up using to access unique data with any of multiple key encodings.  Keep in mind this is a contrived example to illustrate/simplify the real problem.

```
import collections

OfficeEntry = collections.namedtuple('OfficeEntry', ['name', 'short', 'capitol', 'zip'])


class OfficeNameDecoder():

    def __init__(self, office_entries):
        self.data = office_entries

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        """
        """
        for idx, li in enumerate(self.data):
            if key in li:
                return li

        raise IndexError()
```

If we instantiate the OfficeNameDecoder with some sample data:

```
SAMPLE_OFFICE_ENTRIES = [ OfficeEntry('Alabama',  'AL', 'Montgomery', 36043),
                          OfficeEntry('Colorado', 'CO', 'Denver',     80014),
                          OfficeEntry('Florida',  'FL', 'Tallahasse', 32301) ]

ond = OfficeNameDecoder(SAMPLE_OFFICE_ENTRIES)
```

Accounting can get field office zip codes by doing:

```
ond['AL'].zip
>> 36043
```

Finance can get field office zip codes using:

```
ond['Colorado'].zip
>> 80014
```

and I can finally stop fielding phone calls from Legal for state abbreviations:

```
ond['Florida'].short
>> 'FL'
```

Comment: Ouch, that algorithmic complexity.

Answer (score 0):

`Pandas` are quite powerful at this kind of stuff. If you are open to using it, here's the code for it.

**Define a data frame:**

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Alabama', 'Colorado', 'Florida'], 'Short': ['AL', 'CO', 'FL'], 'Capital': ['Montgomery', 'Denver', 'Tallahassee'], 'Zip': [36043, 80014, 32301]})
>>> df
       Capital      Name Short    Zip
0   Montgomery   Alabama    AL  36043
1       Denver  Colorado    CO  80014
2  Tallahassee   Florida    FL  32301
```

**Using state's 2-letter abbreviation to get the zip code:**

```
>>> df[df['Short'] == 'AL']['Zip'].values[0]
36043
```

**Using state's name to get the zip code:**

```
>>> df[df['Name'] == 'Colorado']['Zip'].values[0]
80014
```

**Using state's capital to get the state name:**

```
>>> df[df['Capital'] == 'Tallahassee']['Name'].values[0]
'Florida'
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't think there's a non-database solution for what you are looking for. Two-way memory-efficient injective mappings aren't native to Python, or perhaps to any programming language.

For **small applications** where you can guarantee that mappings between fields are injective, you can define multiple dictionaries. This need not be error-prone, you can use `collections.defaultdict` and `itertools.permutations` to create a dictionary of dictionaries. I only advise this route if your data is small but used many times.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import permutations

data = [{'Name': 'Alabama',  'Short': 'AL', 'Capital': 'Montgomery', 'Zip': 36043},
        {'Name': 'Colorado', 'Short': 'CO', 'Capital': 'Denver', 'Zip': 80014},
        {'Name': 'Florida', 'Short': 'FL', 'Capital': 'Tallahassee', 'Zip': 32301}]

d = defaultdict(dict)

for item in data:
    for key1, key2 in permutations(item.keys(), 2):
        d[(key1, key2)][item[key1]] = item[key2]

defaultdict(dict,
            {('Capital', 'Name'): {'Denver': 'Colorado', 'Montgomery': 'Alabama',
                                   'Tallahassee': 'Florida'},
             ('Capital', 'Short'): {'Denver': 'CO', 'Montgomery': 'AL',
                                    'Tallahassee': 'FL'},
             ...
             ('Zip', 'Name'): {32301: 'Florida', 36043: 'Alabama', 80014: 'Colorado'},
             ('Zip', 'Short'): {32301: 'FL', 36043: 'AL', 80014: 'CO'}})
```